# PHP isset() usage

Tags: php, html

Okay so let me sum it up briefly. I have two textboxes made in html. I want whatever is typed there to be stored into two variables, but I want the page to do two things, one, I want to set the submit button(using isset) so that it does not display an error at the beginning. How would I do this, suppose that my two variables are $textbox1 and $textbox2. The error I get is undefined Variable on line 26 which is where my HTML textbox2 is located. I would also like to note that the value of my textbox is also the variable. If you don't understand me, scroll to the bottom of the code to see what I'm talking about.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $textbox1 = $_Post['txtbox1'] && $textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2']; 
    if ($textbox1=="John" && $textbox2="Doe") {
        Print ("Welcome back friend");
    } else {
        print ("You're not a member of this site");
    }
} else {
    $textbox1="" && $textbox2="";
}
print($textbox1 && $textbox2);

?>


<input type="text" value="<?php print($textbox2); ?>" name=txtbox2>
```

Comment: case-sensitivity: `$_Post['txtbox1']` should be `$_POST['txtbox1']`

Comment: in your HTML form, are you setting the textbox input attribute `name='txtbox1'` and `name='txtbox2'` ? Also, `method='post'` ?

Comment: @verbumSapienti this is one error, but doesn't fix it totally.

Comment: @bwoebi, I know, just checking. `@Crontab` has a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 5):

`&&` is a logic operator.  You can't use it to set multiple variables in a single line.  So

```
$textbox1 = $_Post['txtbox1'] && $textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2'];
```

should read

```
$textbox1 = $_POST['txtbox1'];
$textbox2 = $_POST['txtbox2'];
```

Also, you're using assignment (`=`) instead of an equality check (`==`) in your second conditional.

```
if ($textbox1=="John" && $textbox2="Doe") {
```

should read

```
if ($textbox1 == 'John' && $textbox2 == 'Doe') {
```

Again, in your `else` and the `print()` afterwards, you're attempting to use logic operators when you shouldn't be.  In the else, split it into two separate lines as shown above, and in your `print()` statement you should be using concatenation, not `&&`.

I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish here, but these are problems I see with your code.

Comment: Thank you Crontab. I have a slight issue though. Even when I do switch all the coding to your suggestions, I still get an error when I submit the form. I get an error stating that my variable textbox1 is undefined. I enter both of the correct terms for each textbox and get the error. Also whatever I enter into the second textbox, it is displayed adjacent to "You're not a member of this site"

Comment: Interestingly enough, your errors can be addressed using the `isset()` function.  Ideally, before you use `$textbox1`, you would check that it is set using `if (isset($textbox1))` first and handle the situation appropriately if it is not.  Then you wouldn't get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You're having an undefined variable issue, as `$textbox2` is not always defined... when you submit it and `$_Post["txtbox1"]` evaluates to false when casted to bool, as it is never set as variables are case sensitive in PHP (`$_POST` instead of `$_Post`) then $textbox2 won't be defined.

Your line is parsed as the following:

```
$textbox1 = (($_Post['txtbox1']) && ($textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2']));
```

The `&&` operator only checks as long as every value evaluates to `true`. But `$_Post['txtbox1']` evaluates to false, so it won't never execute the `$textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2']` part, `$textbox2` is not assigned.

The most correct would be:

```
$textbox1 = $_POST['txtbox1'];
$textbox2 = $_POST['txtbox2'];
```

And use in the if clause: `!empty($_POST['txtbox1']) && !empty($_POST['txtbox2'])`

Comment: can you please explain a little more? I did everything Crontab said to do, which made all the errors disappear in the beginning. However When i do submit the form I get errors about undefined variables. I think you're really close to the correct answer.

Comment: @user2235005 simply update your question (new paragraph, not replace old content to show what you've achieved now). If I now try to explain, I don't now what's already correct and what isn't...

Answer (score 0):

```
$textbox1=$_Post['txtbox1'];
$textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2'];
```

don't write them like this

```
$textbox1=$_Post['txtbox1'] 
&& $textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2'];
```

also in `else`

```
$textbox1=""; $textbox2="";
```

in `if` you wrote `=` and that means equal. you should write `==` that means check if it equal this

Answer (score 0):

The && you have specified does not work in case of assignments.
You can only use it in logical conditions.
Try this :

```
$textbox1 = $_Post['txtbox1'];
 $textbox2=$_POST['txtbox2'];
```

Also, instead of using "=" in the conditions, try using "==="
This is the most appropriate operand when you compare two strings.